# Good JQuery Table to render data returned from API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application which uses the new ASP.NET Web API. I have a method which retrieves a list of Enquiries from my database. The problem is I'm not sure what to do with that data now.

I'd like to have it render in a nice table which is filterable, sortable, searchable, pagination etc.. as there are about 40000 enquiries returned. Any suggestions and how I would go about implementing it? Thanks.

### Edit

Here is my Enquiries model:

```
public int EnquiryId { get; set; }
public string CustomerAccountNumber { get; set; }
public string Creator { get; set; }
public string Owner { get; set; }
public DateTime EnquiryDate { get; set; }
public int StatusId { get; set; }
public virtual Status EnquiryStatus { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<EnquiryLines> Lines { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you check out [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/).  It's an open source grid view for jQuery that has -- I think -- all the features you're looking for.  Here are some key features (from the web site):

- Resizable columns
- Resizable height and width
- Sortable column headers
- Cool theme
- Can convert an ordinary table
- Ability to connect to an ajax data source (XML and JSON[new])
- Paging
- Show/hide columns
- Toolbar (new)
- Search (new)
- Accessible API

I think it's a really fantastic control, and it is pretty easy to use.  I think you'll be pleasantly surprised by the flexibility it offers you.  (I'd post a complete example for you, but I'm new to this and don't know how to do that.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I'll take a look into it. To do an example you just have to wrap your code with ` or select it all and press ctrl + k

Answer (score 3):

Try using [datatable](http://datatables.net/) or [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). These are plugins that work with jquery lib.